# If $G/K$ is isomorphic to $H$ then is $G$ isomorphic to $KH$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I don't know if the question is trivial but I would really appreciate if someone could prove/disprove this question.

Thank you in advance

**Edit:**

I meant this: Suppose that there is homomorphism $f$ from $G$ to $H' K = \ker f$ and $H = \operatorname{im} f$. Then by the 1st isomorphism theorem, we can denote that $G/K \simeq H$ now my question was if I can say that $G \simeq K \times H$

Comment: What do you mean by $KH$?

Comment: $KH$ doesn't make sense unless $H$ is a subgroup of $G$.

Comment: I meant this :  
Suppose that there is  homomorphism f from G to H' 
K = ker f and H = image (f)
then by the 1st isomorph theorm we can denote that
G/K≅H
now my question was if I can say that G ≅ K X H

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean $K\times H$ then No.

$\mathbb{Z}_4/\mathbb{Z_2} \cong \mathbb{Z}_2$ but $\dots\dots$